# awk Print Skipping a field

Tags: awk

In the case where type is "" print the 3rd field out of sequence and then print the whole line with the exception of the 3rd field.

Given a tab separated line `a b c d e` the idea is to print `ab<tab>c<tab>a<tab>b<tab>d<tab>e`

Setting `$3=""` seems to cause the subsequent print statement to lose the tab field separators and so is no good.

```
# $1 = year $2 = movie
BEGIN {FS = "\t"} 
  type=="" {printf "%s\t%s\t", $2 $1,$3; $3=""; print}
  type!="" {printf "%s\t<%s>\t", $2 $1,type; print}
END {print ""}
```

Sticking in a for loop which I like a lot less as a solution results in a blank file.

```
# $1 = year $2 = movie
BEGIN {FS = "\t"} 
  type=="" {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t", $2 $1,$3,$1,$2; for (i=4; i<=NF;i++) printf "%s\t",$i}
  type!="" {printf "%s\t<%s>\t", $2 $1,type; print}
END {print ""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the OFS to a tab instead of it's default single blank char and you don't want to just set `$3` to a bank char as then you'll get 2 tabs between `$2` and `$4`.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}
{
    if (type == "") {
        val = $3
        for (i=3; i<NF; i++) {
            $i = $(i+1)
        }
        NF--
    }
    else {
        val = "<" type ">"
    }
    print $2 $1, val, $0
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file | tr '\t' '-'
ba-c-a-b-d-e
$
$ awk -v type="foo" -f tst.awk file | tr '\t' '-'
ba-<foo>-a-b-c-d-e
```

The `|tr '\t' '-'` is obviously just added to make visible where the tabs are.

If decrementing NF doesn't work in your awk to delete the last field in the record, replace it with `sub(/\t[^\t]+$/,"")`.

Comment: Illuminating observations. I'd would rather take care of the double tabs with a post run of tr than insert the for loop into the awk though.

Comment: @IheOnwuka then you could not distinguish between a field that was initially empty vs the field that became empty as a result of you setting `$3=""` so you would corrupt your output.

Comment: Since I control what goes into $3 it is not a concern for my instance of this problem but I agree it is true for others.

Comment: The value of `$3` is not the primary issue, it's the value of the other fields. Look, it's just a plain old bad idea to modify your text with one command and then pipe it to a different command to try to correct any problems you introduced with the first command. Do as you like though, of course.

Comment: You wouldn't want to be doing it where it will cause loads of fix up but it is not a universally a bad idea. Far from it. In my example it is certainly not as clear why the for loop is necessary, whereas running tr a posteriori makes what is going on more apparent. 

This is a judgement call for the individual programmer. Making an initial move that gets you almost there and applying any necessary fixup is a  valid design technique especially if the initial thing you do is relatively simple.

Comment: Another reason I prefer the subsequent running of tr is that the solution doesn't get more complicated if there are additional fields I want to get rid of.

Comment: Do whatever you feel is in your best interests, all you get here is free advice from people completely unaffected by whatever you eventually choose to do.

Comment: Yes. In the course of this discussion I have received free advice for which I am grateful but have also given it for the benefit of the next person who has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way

```
awk '{$3=""}1' OFS="\t" infile|column -t
```

#### explanation

- `{$3=""}` set column to nil
- `1` same as print, print the line.
  OFS="\t"`set Output Field Separator Variable to tab, maybe you needn't it, next command`column -t` make the format again.
- `column -t`  columnate lists with tabs.

Comment: Didn't understand that but accepted it because it led me to read stuff that I did understand.

Comment: that will fail when there are blank chars in the fields and the `column -t` is doing nothing useful.

Comment: The problem is, if you have time, you can make it perfect, like you did.